# how can i prevent CombineLatest to fire the first time

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, combinelatest

I have a form with a bunch of fields (using reactiveForm).
When the value change in field A or B, I want to execute doStuffWithAnB.

so combineLatest seems to be what i need.

```
combineLatest(A.valueChanges,B.valueChanges).subscribe(doStuffWithAnB)
```

now if the user goes in the form, and touches only B (Or A), I want to execute my function, > here comes startWith

```
combineLatest(A.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(someDefaultValue),B.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(someOtherDefaultValue)).subscribe(doStuffWithAnB)
```

but now doStuffWithAnB is fired from the start since my 2 streams have a startWith, but i don't want to execute doStuffWithAnB until one of the fields has been modified

how can i achieve that in a clean way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not go for a `merge` instead which will take either one of the results! We also do not need `startsWith`, since it should not execute initially!

From:

```
 combineLatest(A.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(someDefaultValue),B.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(someOtherDefaultValue)).subscribe(doStuffWithAnB)
```

To:

```
merge(A.valueChanges,B.valueChanges).subscribe(doStuffWithAnB)
```